# Java: Cómo puedo verificar si un elemento de mi arreglo de enteros es nulo

Tags: java, array

¡Hola! Buen día. Soy nuevo en programación en Java y tengo una pregunta sobre arreglos.

¿Cómo puedo comprobar si un array de int tiene un espacio vacío para agregar otro? O, por ejemplo, ¿cómo podemos saber si la media debe ser dividida por otro número que no es la longitud del arreglo?
Por el momento, hice un método que toma "null"=0, sin embargo, 0 puede ser considerado elemento de mi arreglo, es decir, no necesariamente 0 indica que el lugar está vacío:
Ejemplo:

```
int [] a1 = new int [3]
a1 = {1,2}
```

Tiene un lugar vacío.
Cuando tomamos el promedio se debe dividir por 2 y no 3.
En cambio

```
int[] a2 = new int[3]
```

`a2={1,2,0}` tiene un 0 pero no elementos vacíos.
He intentado transformar mi arreglo a una lista, utilizando métodos, pasar un a String (para usar null), pero cuando pruebo los valores en otro archivo, mis estadísticas no son correctas. (promedio desviación estándar...) o me manda errores. Creo que el programa rellena posiciones con ceros.

Gracias por la ayuda. Estos son dos métodos de mi programa:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Estadisticas {
    // Variables
    private int [] arreglo;
    private int nDatos;
public void agregar(int dato) {

    nDatos=getNumDatos(arreglo);     
     if(nDatos>=arreglo.length){
     System.out.println("Arreglo lleno, no se pudo agregar el "+dato);
     } else{

     arreglo[nDatos++]=dato; 
     System.out.println("Se agregó el "+dato);

  }

    }
private int getNumDatos(int [] arregloAux ) {

        int contador =0;
        arreglo=arregloAux;

        for(int j=0;j<arreglo.length;j++){
            if (arreglo[j]!=0){
                contador++;
            }} return contador; 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que tus valores del arreglo tengan un valor por defecto distinto de cero tendrás que hacer un método que recorra la lista y setee los valores a **-1** u otro. Aquí te dejo mi ejemplo de tu problema:

```
package init;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        setValues(a);
        a[0] = 1;
        a[1] = 2;
        toAddValue(4, a);
    }
    public static void setValues(int[] array){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = -1;
    }
    public static void toAddValue(int value, int[] array){
        int k = array.length-1;
        boolean stop = false;
        while(!stop && k >= 0){             //Recorre la lista en reversa, así disminuye el número de recorridos
            stop = array[k] > -1;
            k--;
        }
        if(k == array.length)
            System.out.println("Arreglo lleno, no se pudo agregar el "+value);
        else{
            array[k+2] = value;             //Se le suma 2 pq' antes de terminar el ciclo le quite 1 a k
            System.out.println("Se agregó el "+value);
        }
    }
}
```

PD: No es necesario que en este caso (nDatos>=arreglo.length) uses un mayor igual ya que nDatos nunca va a ser mayor **arreglo.length** ni que (arreglo[nDatos++]=dato;) uses **++** porque nDatos ya contiene la posición vacía, ademas que al ponerlo detras de nDatos suma al final y no influye en el resultado, pero si estuviera delante nDatos incrementará antes de cambiar el valor y lo pondría 1 posición después.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción distinta a las que te han dado (aunque yo me decantaría por la del uso de ArrayList) es usar las clases envolventes (wrapper class) en lugar de los tipos primitivos.

Al declarar un array de un tipo primitivo los elementos cogen su valor por defecto. El valor por defecto de int es 0, el de boolean es false, short es 0, etc. Aquí te dejo un enlace con información al respecto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Dicho esto podrías usar la clase envolvente de int que es Integer. Al ser una clase y no un tipo primitivo su valor por defecto es null, por lo que para comprobar si se ha asignado valor a un elemento de un arreglo de Integer solo tendrías que hacer la siguiente comprobación:

```
    Integer[] asd = new Integer[2];
    asd[0] = 1;
    System.out.println(asd[0] + " y " + asd[1]);
    if(asd[1] == null) {
        asd[1] = 2;
    }

    System.out.println(asd[0] + " y " + asd[1]);
```

La salida por consola es la siguiente:

```
1 y null
1 y 2
```

Lo que si debes tener en cuenta si usas las clases envolventes es que debes controlar siempre nulos para evitar el famoso y temido NullPointerException.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> ¿Cómo puedo comprobar si un array de int tiene un espacio vacío para agregar otro?

Aqui te muestro un ejemplo de como puedes comprobar que un arreglo de enteros de 'N' posiciones verifique si tiene posiciones disponibles:

[Ejemplo en Vivo](http://tpcg.io/Aejphq)

```
public class Comprobacion
  {
   private static Boolean estaMiArregloLLeno(int[] array) 
   {
      int count = 0;
      for(int i : array)
      {
         if(i > 0)
         {
            count++;
         }
      }
      return count == array.length;
   }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         int [] a1 = new int[3];
         a1[0] = 1;
         a1[1] = 2;
         a1[2] = 0;

         System.out.println(Comprobacion.estaMiArregloLLeno(a1) ? "El arreglo esta lleno": "El arreglo aun no esta lleno");


    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Los arreglos son un tipo de dato que perite almacenar una serie de elementos del mismo tipo bajo una misma variable. El tamaño de un arreglo es fijo e implícitamente no existe eso de que un arreglo está vacío, lleno o tienes espacios libres. Para manejar estos conceptos debes utilizar variables adicionales que te permitan saber la cantidad de elementos que has agregado al arreglo. Por defecto, si declaras un arreglo de enteros y lo inicializas de esta forma: `int[] arreglo = new int[5]`, a cada posición se le asigna 0 como valor. Pero, como tu mismo comentas, si lo inicializas así: `arreglo = {0, 5, 0, 1, 9}`, igual contiene ceros, por lo que no puedes decir que porque el valor de una posición sea 0 indica que está vacía.

En tu caso te recomiendo que utilices la clase `ArrayList` que es una estructura de datos de tipo lista cuya implementación utiliza un arreglo para almacenar los elementos, pero también utiliza las variables que te comento que le permiten determinar si este está lleno o vacío.

```
public class Estadisticas {
    // Variables
    private ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public void agregar(int dato) {
        lista.add(dato);
    }

    // Más código
}
```